# How to detect empty margin space on a webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, margin

How to detect empty margin space on a webpage using javascript?

Consider that I have a multiple sites having multiple page background with different margins.
so I need to detect empty margins before onload of pages using javascript tag which will be something like 3rd party js tag.
It should be like autodetect feature to do further actions based on the margin being empty or not.